# arcpy.da.UpdateCursor with sql_clause for artifically inverting cursor loops

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, sql, cursor

Why is row not recognized within my update cursor?

The data is stored in a file geodatabase.
I am using ArcGIS Desktop version 10.1 ArcInfo License.

The screen shot shows the data "ORDER BY X ASC" with some values assigned.
Now I'm trying to reverse sort and continue adding values in the last column.

I know cursors don't work backwards, so I thought reversing the sort might be a good work around.

```
import arcpy
import itertools

fc = r"C:\Data\Workspace.gdb\MyFeatureClass"
sql_rev = (None, "ORDER BY X DESC")

inc = itertools.count(13,1)
expression = "{0} = 1 AND {1} = 1".format("Gpriority", "FlightID")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FlightLnOrder", "X"], expression, sql_clause = sql_rev) as uCur:
    c = 1
    for row in uCur:
        c += 1
        if c == 2:
            row[0] = inc.next()
            c = 0
            uCur.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: you need to indent the with block and then not try to del row or cursor.. the with block handles all that. The whole del line needs to be removed, none of those are objects that exist by the time the del statement is hit.

Comment: The indentation was an artifact of my adding the code to stack exchange. I am aware that the "with block" handles the deletion of objects, but it was useful to help quickly debug. The line "for row in uCur:" doesn't engage and values are not being written?

Comment: Perhaps it's the order that's causing the fouling.. from the help http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000 DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and ALL are only supported when working with databases. If you're working with a shapefile you can't order the rows.

Comment: It is very confusing... I noticed that in the help files also, but the feature class is held within a file geodatabase, it isn't a shapefile. I am able to use the update cursor with an ORDER BY sql on the same field when selecting rows with no records. However, when I make the above selection which already has those 1 - 12 values written, the cursor doesn't want to work?

Comment: Have you tried just straight SQL: sql_rev =  "ORDER BY X DESC"? I can not find any working examples of this 2nd SQL statement and haven't tried such myself. I am assuming X is a valid field name to order by.

Comment: File geodatabase is NOT a database.

Comment: I just tried your suggested SQL here, but the clause requires 2 strings (prefix, postfix). X is a valid field name as shown in the image, it is a field of longitude values. I'm going to try playing with some of the other prefix options. If that doesn't work, create a feature layer with my ordered selection then try the update cursor on that.

Comment: Can you try importing into a personal geodatabase and running from there.. if Vince is correct then it should work from a Microsoft (JET) Access personal geodatabase - the help specifically mentions Access database as a working database. You could also try '' instead of None in the sql_clause.

Comment: That solved it, thanks guys! I wasn't aware that a file geodatabase was not  a database. Using a personal geodatabase solved the problem.

Comment: Can you put this together as an answer to your own question, I think a working example of an update cursor with sql_clause would be invaluable.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly utilize the arcpy.da.UpdateCursor with an sql_clause you need to ensure your feature class is stored within a database, not a File Geodatabase or as a Shapefile in folder. In the provided solution a Microsoft (JET) Access personal geodatabase is utilized, however other databases can provide improved efficiencies with 64-bit support.

If your data is stored in a File Geodatabase the sql_clause may still function, but it can be unreliable or not work at all when attempting to process rows which already have values written to them.

The following link is provided to reference optional pairs of SQL prefix and postfix clauses organized in a list or tuple.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000

Below is the corrected code used to update the above table as shown. Reminder: the above table already had an update cursor run on it with an "ORDER BY X ASC" sql_clause.

```
import arcpy
import itertools

fc = r"C:\Data\New Personal Geodatabase.mdb\MyFeatureClass"
sql_rev = (None, "ORDER BY X DESC")

inc = itertools.count(13,1)
expression = "{0} = 1 AND {1} = 1".format("Gpriority", "FlightID")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FlightLnOrder", "X"], expression, sql_clause = sql_rev) as uCur:
    c = 1
    for row in uCur:
        c += 1
        if c == 2:
            row[0] = inc.next()
            c = 0
            uCur.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

**Note for multiple arcpy.da.UpdateCursors with an sql_clause:**

If you are attempting to use multiple arcpy.da.UpdateCursors, each with their own sql_clause, you need to wrap both cursors within an edit session and all data needs to be stored in a database.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000
"Opening simultaneous insert or update operations on the same workspace using different cursors requires the start of an edit session."
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Editor/018w00000005000000/